# How does one apply the chain rule to statements like P(A,B|C,D)

Tags: probability, statistics

In a math-y book I'm reading, the authors offer a proof that an equation can be rewritten in a different way. I'm really struggling to understand the proof because at one step, the chain rule from probability theory is invoked to rewrite an expression. I just can't follow this application of the chain rule. In schematic form, the issue is that I just don't know how to apply the chain rule to statements with the following form P(A,B|C,D).

With that prelude out of the way, the authors say that the following is true by the chain rule:

P(Rep1, Rep2|R1, R2) = P(Rep1|Rep2, R1, R2) P(Rep2|R1, R2).

My question is just this: How does applying the chain rule get you from the left side of that equation to the right side? I don't know how to apply the rule to statements of the form P(A,B|C,D). As embarrassing as this is, a case like that has never come up in the discrete math and elementary stats classes I've taken, so I'm just kind of bumfuzzled about how to handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For three events $A,B,C$ with $\mathbb{P}(B\cap C)>0$, then by grouping $(A\cap B)\cap C$ vs. $A\cap (B\cap C)$, we have $$\mathbb{P}(A\cap B|C)\mathbb{P}(C)=\mathbb{P}((A\cap B)\cap C)=\mathbb{P}(A\cap (B\cap C))=\mathbb{P}(A|B\cap C)\mathbb{P}(B\cap C).$$

We can apply this with $A=\text{Rep}_1$, $B=\text{Rep}_2$, $C=R_1\cap R_2$.

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful. If I could ask a couple of questions, that would be awesome. On the left side, why do you have ℙ(∩|)ℙ()? Specifically, where did ℙ() come from? Finally, on the right side, I'm somewhat puzzled by ℙ(∩) rather than ℙ(|).  What I'm looking for is how to get from ℙ(∩|) to ℙ(|∩)ℙ(|). I don't *quite* know how to square that with getting from ℙ(∩|)ℙ() to ℙ(|∩)ℙ(∩). I'm sorry if I'm being dense. I think I'm closer to understanding it now and really appreciate the help.

Comment: Update: Nevermind the first part, I know where P(C) came from. P(A,B,C) = P(A,B|C) P(C) by the multiplication rule. So the only remaining thing I'm stumped by is the ℙ(∩) rather than ℙ(|) at the end of the right-hand side. I see how the equations work out, but I'm wondering about the correspondence between that and what I have been wanting to show because we have the intersection sign rather than the 'conditional on' sign (|) where I was expecting it.

Comment: I think an additional step would be useful: $P(B \cap C) = P(B|C)P(C)$. In particular combining with the above yields $$P(A \cap B|C)P(C) = P(A|(B \cap C)P(B \cap C)$$ [as above] $$= P(A|B\cap C)P(B|C)P(C)$$ So in particular  $$P(A \cap B|C)P(C) = P(A|B\cap C)P(B|C)P(C).$$ Divide by $P(C)$ on both sides....

Comment: Oh hell yeah, thanks @Mike. This is exactly what I was missing. God, I think my brain isn't working well today. It's what I get for picking up a math-y text without warming up a bit.

Comment: Glad I could help, good answer @jwhite +1

Answer (score 1):

**Just the above answer by @jwhite elaborated--one more step added for clarity.**

Let us set $X = \text{Rep}_1$;  $Y = \text{Rep}_2$; $Z= R_1 \cap R_2$.

Then we want to evaluate ${\bf{P}}[X \cap Y|Z]$, as that is the LHS of the equation in the OP.

However, the chain rule, applied $3$ times below, gives

$${\bf{P}}[X \cap Y|Z]\cdot{\bf{P}}[Z] = {\bf{P}}[(X \cap Y) \cap Z]$$
$$={\bf{P}}[X \cap (Y \cap Z)] = {\bf{P}}[X|Y \cap Z]\cdot{\bf{P}}[Y \cap Z]$$
$$={\bf{P}}[X|Y \cap Z]\cdot{\bf{P}}[Y|Z] \cdot {\bf{P}}[Z].$$

In particular:

$${\bf{P}}[X \cap Y|Z]\cdot{\bf{P}}[Z] = {\bf{P}}[X|Y \cap Z]\cdot{\bf{P}}[Y|Z] \cdot {\bf{P}}[Z],$$
and thus, dividing both sides by ${\bf{P}}[Z]$ [note that this must be nonzero!] gives the equation
$${\bf{P}}[X \cap Y|Z] \  = {\bf{P}}[X|Y \cap Z]\cdot{\bf{P}}[Y|Z].$$
This is indeed what the OP was trying to show.